# Comments added in Scenario Outline do not appear in HTML reports

Tags: comments, karate

I am using comments for documenting and separating code in Scenario Outline but none of the comments are displayed in HTML reports. When I run the same code as Scenario I can see the comments.

I see a similar issue logged and fixed but I do not see any of the comments I added in the code I executed.
https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1607

I am using karate version 1.0.0.

Thanks.

Comment: not yet released, but use 1.1.0.RC3 if you dare